# Passing the arguments to a website

Tags: dynamic, web, path, arguments, url-routing

Well the title is tricky. I was not sure if this has been already there and how to put it.

Example:

> Lets suppose my site is accessible: 
>   http://mysite.com

if mysite does additions: with 2 inputs

Now If the end user need to pass an argument to site like this (so i load the page like this):

> http://mysite.com/argument1/argument2

so it should be able to thus go to the result directly: arg1+arg2

This brings to the question:when user types this, how can i retreive argument1 and argument2 and load my site according to that? Is it possible? If yes, Any client site programming solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after searching a lot. The correct term for this process is URL-routing. We can overcome this by using #.

> www.mysite.com/#/argu1/argu2

Then in the document.ready() we can read the url in the following manner:

> var url = window.location;

More sophisticated way is to use the "backbone.js" for the routing. The documentation on the link explains everything

> [Backbone.js routing](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/)